# How do I stop searching after the word (regex, grep)?

Tags: regex, linux, perl, grep

Hi I want to stop searching once I get to the end of the word.

For example:

```
ls -al | grep adh
```

Thats my search... I want to stop after the "h"

The directory i'm searching in has two instances of `adh`, there is `adh2` and `adh`... I just want `adh` not `adh2`!

Hope this makes sense, any questions please ask :)

F.Y.I 
I am a Linux/perl Beginner!

Comment: What's wrong with just using `ls -al *adh`?

Comment: You might want to remove the perl tag.  This is not related to perl.

Comment: @Phylogenesis Could still list `aadh` `acadh` .... and so on. So, why not simply `ls -ld adh`

Answer (score 4):

Use the `$` for end of line:

```
ls -al | grep " adh$"
```

should make it.

#### Test

```
$ touch faaa
$ touch faaa2
$ touch faaa3
$ touch afaaa

$ ls -al | grep faaa
-rw-rw-r-- 1 me me    0 Jul 25 14:24 afaaa
-rw-rw-r-- 1 me me    0 Jul 25 14:24 faaa
-rw-rw-r-- 1 me me    0 Jul 25 14:24 faaa2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 me me    0 Jul 25 14:24 faaa3

$ ls -al | grep faaa$
-rw-rw-r-- 1 me me    0 Jul 25 14:24 afaaa
-rw-rw-r-- 1 me me    0 Jul 25 14:24 faaa

$ ls -al | grep " faaa$"
-rw-rw-r-- 1 me me    0 Jul 25 14:24 faaa
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should specify what is allowed after the your `adh`.

Fedorqui's answer is ok, if the your words are at the end of line, so the:

```
adh$
```

mean - match `adh` and the end of line.

This will not works for the space delimited words, like

```
adh something
adh2 another
```

in similar cases, you should write:

```
grep 'adh '
```

match `adh` and `<space>` or

```
grep `adh[^a-z0-9A-Z]`
```

match `adh` and anything but letters and numbers, or you can use `perl regex`

```
grep -P `adh\b`
```

the end of `adh` should be word boundary

and so on... Probably, more skillfull regex-experts will suggest more possibilites..

Answer (score 0):

In general:

```
command that generates output | grep pattern | head -1
```

gives you the first occurence of pattern in the lines printed by the command. Like:

```
ls -l | grep " adh$" | head -1
```

Comment: Although the result is the desired, I guess it is not a matter of getting just the first result but to skipping the `adh[something]` ones.

Comment: Yeah, whatever "stop after the 'h'" means .... but as long as it is sorted lexicograpically, it makes no difference.

Comment: @fedorqui I have updated the pattern (inspired by your solution), but note that it isn't general either: We could have "aadc" and "adc", for example.

Comment: Uhms, good point. Maybe we could change the `ls -l` (L) to `ls -1` (one) and do `grep "^adh$"` to match *exactly* `adh`.

Comment: @fedorqui I think `grep " adh$"` is the best we can do, though it will also match more than one when there is a file named "blue adh" besides "adh". That being said, file names with spaces should be rare on Linux and whoever uses them deserves punishment.

Answer (score 0):

`grep` has a `-w` option for this:

```
        -w, --word-regexp
           Select  only  those  lines  containing  matches  that form whole
           words.  The test is that the matching substring must  either  be
           at  the  beginning  of  the  line,  or  preceded  by  a non-word
           constituent character.  Similarly, it must be either at the  end
           of  the  line  or  followed by a non-word constituent character.
           Word-constituent  characters  are  letters,  digits,   and   the
           underscore.
```

So in your case, `grep -w adh` should do what you want.

Comment: Not if this is run in a directory where the user `adh` created some files.

Comment: @Ingo If the intention is to search only for file names, that's true. That wasn't really specified in the OP, though - just searching for the "word". To avoid finding usernames, just drop the `-l` from `ls`... Or use `awk '$NF == "adh" {print}`.

Comment: The answer of @fedorqui already does similar functionality with `grep " adh$"`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starters - don't parse `ls` that's just generally bad news.

But as this is tagged `perl` I shall offer a perlish answer:

```
perl -e 'print join "\n", grep { /adh\b/ } glob "*"'
```

`glob` expands a directory pattern.

`grep` is ... like grep, in that it takes regex, but it can actually take arbitrary code blocks too.

(So you could, for example:

```
grep { -f && /adh\b/ }
```

To filter for *just* files (`-f` file test) with that name. Or run a `stat` or something.

`join` does what it says - sticks together multiple results with the join character, in this case a line feed.

Comment: Sigh. Got caught out by a 'bump'.

Answer (score -2):

You can try this:

```
ls -al | grep -Fx adh
```

Where,

```
-F, --fixed-strings
```

Interpret PATTERN as a (list of) fixed strings.

```
-x, --line-regexp
```

Select only those matches that exactly match the whole line.

Comment: hm... so `echo something adh2 | grep -F adh` ?

Comment: You can use the -m switch with grep.
grep -m 1 pattern file, stops after the first match.
Do refer the man page : http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep

Comment: The OP don't want match `adh2` - only `adh`. Try yourself the above. Your answer doesn't works, because `grep -F adh` will match `adh2` too. Refer the cited man page, what `fixed strings` really means...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. My bad.